# Logging the location on the server - Robot Framework/CMD

Tags: cmd, server, location, robotframework, pwd

I'm trying to log in to the database server with applications run there. I can login without any problems, however when I try to log the working directory on the server it shows me the default directory after logging in and not the one i changed.

Whole testcase looks like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SSHLibrary

*** Variables ***
${IP}  IP
${user}  user
${password}  password
*** Test Cases ***
CMD
    Open connection  ${IP}
    login  ${user}  ${password}
    execute command  cd gtms/bin
    ${pwd}  execute commanrd  pwd
    log  ${pwd}
```

And I am expecting to get info about the directory I am in when I use pwd, but it is not working. I get this in LOG:

```
KEYWORD BuiltIn . Log ${pwd}
Documentation:  
Logs the given message with the given level.
Start / End / Elapsed:  20170807 16:07:14.266 / 20170807 16:07:14.267 /         
00:00:00.001
16:07:14.267    INFO    /home/ollie
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is result code of that `cd` command? You can have it with `return_rc=True` for `Execute Command`.

Comment: Is this your actual code? I ask that because `execute commanrd` is spelled wrong and should throw an error.

Comment: Added return_rc=True and got in the LOG:
    KEYWORD SSHLibrary . Execute Command cd gtms/bin, 
    return_rc=True
    Documentation: 
    Executes `command` on the remote machine and returns its outputs.
    Start / End / Elapsed: 20170808 08:51:19.274 / 20170808         
    08:51:19.305 / 00:00:00.031
    08:51:19.274 INFO Executing command 'cd gtms/bin'. 
    08:51:19.305 INFO Command exited with return code 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Execute Command` always runs the specified command(s) in a new shell - thus the `cd` in the first call is not persisted, as visible by the `pwd` in the second call. This actually is the example in its [documentation](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/latest/SSHLibrary.html#Execute%20Command) :

```
The command is always executed in a new shell. Thus possible changes to the environment (e.g. changing working directory) are not visible to the later keywords:
${pwd}= Execute Command pwd
Should Be Equal ${pwd}  /home/johndoe
Execute Command cd /tmp 
${pwd}= Execute Command pwd
Should Be Equal ${pwd}  /home/johndoe
```

In order to achieve what you want, just chain the target commands, and execute once:

```
${output}=    Execute Command  cd gtms/bin; pwd
Log    ${output}    # will log the output of the executed command(s) - in this case, pwd
```

Comment: That is really helpful. How can I then log pwd from the chained commands to check if that really works?

Comment: That's not only helpful, that's the answer ;) The `Execute Command` returns the output of whatever is executed - in this case, the chained commands, so you just assign it to a variable, and do whatever is needed. I've updated the answer to include it.

Comment: Added what you suggested but the output is still wrong:
KEYWORD ${output} = SSHLibrary . Execute Command cd gtms/bin; pwd
Executes `command` on the remote machine and returns its outputs.
Start / End / Elapsed: 20170809 13:14:24.004
13:14:24.004 INFO Executing command 'cd gtms/bin; pwd'. 
13:14:24.280 INFO Command exited with return code 0. 
13:14:24.280 INFO ${output} = /home/ollie 
00:00:00.000KEYWORD BuiltIn . Log ${output}
Logs the given message with the given level.
Start / End / Elapsed: 20170809 13:14:24.281
13:14:24.281 INFO /home/ollie

Comment: The system doesn't cd - are you sure there is a directory `/home/ollie/gtms/bin`? Go to the shell with the user ollie, and execute `cd`, and then `cd gtms/bin; pwd` - what is the output? If the directory doesn't exist, it will most probably be "/home/ollie" on 1 line - that's the stdout, and something like "-bash: cd: gtms/bin: No such file or directory" - that's the error for the non-existing directory, in stderr.

Comment: It works now. Seems like during my vacation there was a change in structure and gtms/bin was moved to another directory. Sorry for the confusion and thank you very much for answering my question.